# How to Remove assigned tags if the product becomes out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, product, stock, tags

When any product's quantity becomes 0 or out of stock i need to remove all the tags assigned to that particular product.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to create a module for that.

First create the `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Then you need to observe the `cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after` that is dispatched when the stock of a product is changed as well as `catalog_product_save_after` in case the stock status is changed.

`app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
        <models>  
            <module>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
        <events>
                <catalog_product_save_after>
                    <observers>
                        <vendor_module_catalog_product_save_after>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>module/observer</class>
                            <method>afterProductSave</method>
                        </vendor_module_catalog_product_save_after>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_save_after>
                <cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
                    <observers>
                        <vendor_module_cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>module/observer</class>
                            <method>afterStockSave</method>
                        </vendor_module_cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
                    </observers>
                </cataloginventory_stock_item_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </global> 
</config>
```

Then in `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer {

    public function afterStockSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $_item = $event->getItem();

        if ((int)$_item->getData('qty') == 0) {
            $productId = $_item->getProductId();
            $tags = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/collection')->addProductFilter($productId)->delete();
        }
    }

    public function afterProductSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $stockData = $product->getStockData();

        if ((int)$stockData['qty'] == 0 || !$stockData['is_in_stock']) {
            $productId = $product->getProductId();
            $tags = Mage::getResourceModel('tag/collection')->addProductFilter($productId)->delete();
        }
    }
}
```